# Is $C_{00}$ a subspace of $l^1$ or at least a subset?

Tags: functional-analysis

I know $C_{00}$ a subspace of  $l^{\infty}$, but I wonder if it is also a subspace of $l^1$ or at least a subset. Since being in $l^1$ means being an absolutely convergent series, and elements in $C_{00}$ have finitely-many non-zero components, the sum of the components of an element in $C_{00}$ is finite, that is the series is finite and therefore $C_{00} \subseteq l^{1}$. The linear combinations of two elements in $C_{00}$ still have finitely-many elements, so they must stay in $C_{00}$, therefore $C_{00}$ must be a subspace of  $l^1$. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: This is correct, it is a subspace of $l^1$.

Comment: Thanks guys, @David Mitra , as a side thing I know $l^1 \subset l^2$, but is it a subspace?

Comment: Yes, for the same reasons $c_{00}$ is a subspace of $\ell_1$ (it is a vector subspace).